# Issues selecting and deleting nodes with XPATH and PHP DOM

Tags: php, xpath, domdocument

Probably a stupid question but so far I can't figure this out...

I have an XHTML document as a string. It's in `$temp` So far so good. I want to do two things. I want to select all meta tags in the body (they are there because of their use in conjunction with microdata) and then delete them. After deleting the microdata properties that is.

```
    $xml=new DOMDocument();
    $xml->loadXML($temp);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
    $attr = $xpath->query("//@itemscope|//@itemprop|//@itemtype|//@itemid|//@itemref");
    foreach ($attr as $entry)
        $entry->parentNode->removeAttribute($entry->nodeName);
```

That works. But I can't manage to select any nodes with Xpath.

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml); // thought I had to update this after changing the XML
echo $xpath->query("//body")->length; // => 0
echo $xml->getElementsByTagName("body")->length; // => 1
```

So Question No. 1: How do I select nodes with Xpath. Why doesn't this work?

This works to get the node list though:

```
$node = $xml->getElementsByTagName("body")->item(0)->getElementsByTagName("meta");
```

I figured to remove the nodes I'd use this: (similar to removing the attributes above)

```
foreach ($node as $entry)
{
    $entry->parentNode->removeChild($entry);
}
```

But the nodes remain.

So there is Question No. 2: How to remove nodes from an XML file.

Specifically meta nodes anywhere in any body node.

Thanks.

**UPDATE**

Let me add an HTML test case:

```
$temp='<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body id="dok" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" >
        <div><div><div><meta itemprop="dummy" content="something"/></div></div></div>
        <span><meta itemprop="dummy2" content="something2"/></span>
    </body>
</html>';
```

With the above the xPath trying to select the body give me a length of 0 and I can't remove all meta tags from the body...

**UPDATE**

This works with the loadXML() method:

```
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$xpath->registerNamespace("x","http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml");
echo $xpath->query("//x:body")->length;
```

**SOLUTION without namespaces**

It was about the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` namespace in the root `html` tag all along. `//body` selects any body tag that is **NOT** part of any namespace. Since we did specify a default namespace and `body` is part of that namespace `//body`won't select it. I have no idea under what name to access the namespace already intrinsic to the XHTML without declaring it under a name but if we strip it off before creating the XML all is fine. After we're done we can add it back in..

```
    $temp =  str_replace('xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"','',$temp);
    $xml=new DOMDocument();
    $xml->loadXML($temp);
    $xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);    
    $attr = $xpath->query("//@itemscope|//@itemprop|//@itemtype|//@itemid|//@itemref");
    foreach ($attr as $entry)
        $entry->parentNode->removeAttribute($entry->nodeName);
    $node = $xpath->query("//body//meta");
    foreach ($node as $entry)
    {
        $entry->parentNode->removeChild($entry);
    }   
    $temp=$xml->saveXML();
    $temp =  str_replace('<html','<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"',$temp);
```

that way `//body//meta` works just as expected...

Comment: Let me guess: You have an XHTML document?

Comment: @Tomalak yes I have an XHTML document as a string, but badly mistyped that :-) so I fixed it.

Comment: You can try using `$xml->loadHTML($temp);`, which is able to load even malformed stuff quite well. Q1A: should work. `//body` looks good to me, you can try `//head/meta` as well to directly access the meta elements via xpath.

Comment: @hakre The XHTML is served as application/xml it's not malformed. loadXML should be fine. `//body` does not work for me and the meta tags are in the body... I updated the question with a dummy `$temp`. `echo $xpath->query("//head")->length;` doesn't work with the example but `echo $xpath->query("//@charset")->length;`works just fine.

Comment: @C.O.: I see, checking this, because with a W3C xhtml document I got it to work w/o probs.

Comment: This is the biggest FAQ for XPath: The XHTML elements are in the XHTML namespace (usually used as default namespace) but in your XPath expression you are trying to access elements with names that are in "no namespace". You need to register the XHTML namespace with prefix (say "x:") bound to it. The use: `x:body` instead of `body`.

Comment: I could not explain the why, but as for `loadHtml()` "solves" that issue. I'll try to get my example working with namespaces as well. Thanks for the pointer Dimitre.

Comment: @hakre Thanks, So it was the `$xml->loadXML($temp);` all along... Fascinating. I have no clue about the namespaces yet but I'll have to find out how those work... @Dimitre Novatchev can you explain how to do that for XHTML5 content or point somewhere to start reasing? The FAQ was not a link before (if it was intended to be one)

Comment: C.O., I added a `loadXML()` compatible variant. The namespace from the document needs to be registered so xpath knows which elements are addressed in the query.

Comment: You access the default namespace w/o specifying it, e.g. `//body` is body in default namespace. `//xhtml:body` is the body element in the namespace that has been registered with xpath as `xhtml`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This piece of code does the job for me:

```
$temp='<!DOCTYPE html>
<html xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml" xml:lang="de" lang="de">
    <head>
        <meta charset="utf-8"/>
    </head>
    <body id="dok" itemscope="itemscope" itemtype="http://schema.org/WebPage" >
        <div><div><div><meta itemprop="dummy" content="something"/></div></div></div>
        <span><meta itemprop="dummy2" content="something2"/></span>
    </body>
</html>';


$xml=new DOMDocument();
$xml->loadHtml($temp);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml); // thought I had to update this after changing the XML
$path = "//body//meta";

echo $xpath->query($path)->length, "\n"; # 2

foreach ($xpath->query($path) as $entry)
{
    $entry->parentNode->removeChild($entry);
}

echo $xpath->query($path)->length, "\n"; # 0
```

I think the two key points are:

1. **Load the document as HTML** - I can not explain it properly but I think that XML is introducing namespaces and those should be reflected for the xpath. But I'm not familiar with namespace that well to really explain it. Loading as HTML however makes the queries to work *"as expected"* which is technically spoken not the right expection.
2. **`//body//meta`** - The xpath must reflect that there can be more elements between the body and the meta elements. Hence the `//` between `body` and `meta`.

### Namespaces and XML

Thanks to the explanation by Dimitri, I could now better understand the namespace issue I only smelled and could update the code to a loadXML() compatible version (only the modified lines):

```
$xml->loadXml($temp);
$xpath = new DOMXPath($xml);
$xpath->registerNamespace('xhtml', 'http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml');
$path = "//xhtml:body//xhtml:meta";
```

This loads the document as XML. Then it registers the namespace URI from the document with the name `xhtml` for the xpath object.

The xpath query then was modified to reflect the namespace properly for the elements expressions.

Comment: @hakre Ah I see we worked this through simultaneously. Nothing works without an explicit workspace... I didn't know that.

Comment: Well the point is, if the XHTML document does not have the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` within it's root `html` element, then this would not be needed. So if the input documents change, it's probably more fail-safe to still use `loadHtml();`. I wonder how to register one namespace as default.

Comment: @hakre it does have the `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` within it's root `html`element and it always did... Even the above dummy `$temp` html had it...

Comment: @hakre it is the other way around! Not the lack of `xmlns="http://www.w3.org/1999/xhtml"` but its presence is what causes the issues in the first place... See my addition to the question on how to do without the namespace and with plain `//body//meta`

Comment: @C.O. You misunderstood me, that was hypothetical: *if it does not contain* then all elements are in the default namespace. And you even adopted quickly: As I wrote, if the documents do not contain that string. And you remove it from the documents to achieve that. Voila. It's not an issue, it's how xpath works. If the document contain a namespace, you need to register it with xpath. If you remove that namespace (as you do now) then the default namespace applies to all elements in the document that are non-namespaced and you do not need to register a namespace for xpath.

Comment: @hakre Indeed I missed your 'not' before.

Comment: Yeah it's late things get mixed. At least over here ;) Take care!